# separation after for loop

Tags: c++

have input file contain equation want to know dependency between the equation.

separate each equation to input and output in two array "in and out"
here in my function I compare between my two array "in and out"
to know which equation depend in another by using "find".

How could I put only dependent input in array and independent in another array not like my output here?

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMuEC.png)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int count = 0, num = 0, num1 = 0, plu, value_is = 0, count_indd = 1;
string str, str1, str2, str3, plu1, str_ind;
string independent[100], dependent[100], out[100], in[100];

void sepa() {
  ifstream file("in.txt");  // read input file
  for (int k = 0; getline(file, str); k++)

  {
    count++;
    out[k] = str.substr(0, 1);

    if (str.find("+") != -1) {
      plu = str.find("+");
      in[k] = str.substr(2, plu + 1);
    } else {
      plu = str.find("*");
      in[k] = str.substr(2, plu + 1);
    }
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////dependancY
void independ(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    str1 = out[i];
    for (int a = 0; a < count; a++) {
      str2 = in[a];
      if (str2.find(str1) != std::string::npos) {
        dependent[num] = str2;
        cout << "dep   =  " << dependent[num] << endl;
        num++;
      } else {
        independent[num1] = str2;
        cout << "indep = " << independent[num1] << "\n";
        num1++;
      }
    }
  }
}

void depend(void) {
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    str1 = out[i];
    for (int a = 0; a < count; a++) {
      str2 = in[a];
      dependent[num1] = str2;
      cout << "dep  =  " << dependent[num1] << endl;
      num1++;
      break;
    }
  }
}

///////main

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int addnum = atoi(argv[2]);  // read number of add
  int mulnum = atoi(argv[4]);  // read number of multiplier

  sepa();
  // if(str2.find(str1) == std::string::npos)
  //{
  independ();
  //}
  /*if(str2.find(str1) != std::string::npos)
  {
      depend();
  }*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: relevant code should be in your question, along with a description of the specific issue are facing. The `output` link doesn't shed a lot of light on the situation since we can't tell what is input and what is output. Additionally, post the code itself, screenshots are nearly useless for us.

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: `str1 = out[i]` what is `str1`? What is `out`? What in your output is not what you expect? How is it different?

Comment: my input file has equation ... a=b+c / v=t+p / h=a*s ...etc   i want to know   dependency between the equation

Comment: i post my whole code ...

Comment: Can you explain what is going wrong in the code, maybe a specific area in your code that you know is not working but other areas are working?

Comment: my code is working but  in independ function ,  i expect to separate independent equation in independent array and dependent equation in dependent array .. ( example : input file has these equation " a=b+c , f=d*t , w=a+r , t=e+v" i want this function to put " d*t , a+r," in my dependent array     and " b+c, e+v" in my independent array )

Comment: The `*`s in your comments are messing with the formatting, can you surround your equestions with backticks like \`f=d\*t\`

Comment: Those aren't backticks, backticks are under the `~` on the keyboard

Comment: example ( input file has these equation "   `a=b+c` , `f=d*t`  , ` w=a+r` , `t=e+v`  " i want this function to put " `d*t` , `a+r` " in my dependent array and " `b+c` , `e+v` " in my independent array )

Answer (score 0):

So first let us decompose your problem.

`a=b+c` represents an equation, which can be further divided into :
 * `base` => `a`
 * `dependencies` => `b` and `c`

Now your problem becomes, read all the equations from a file, and check whether the `dependencies` of your equation depend on some base.
If yes, mark it as `dependent` equation.
If no, mark it as `independent` equation.

Hence `a=b+c` is an independent equation, since dependency `b` or `c` are not a base of any equation.
While `w=a+r` is a dependent equation, since dependency `a` is also a base somewhere.

Fair enough ?

So let us begin by creating an `equation` class.
`equation` stores original `line`, its `base` and its `dependencies`.
`dependencies` is an array(`std::vector`) of tokens.
It also provides a mechanism to `print` the `equation`.

```
struct equation
{
    equation(std::string              const & line,
             std::string              const & base,
             std::vector<std::string> const & dependencies)
        : line(line), base(base), dependencies(dependencies) {}

    void print() const {
        std::cout << "Equation => [" << line 
                  << "]; Base => [" << base 
                  << "]; Deps => [";
        for(int i = 0; i < dependencies.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << dependencies[i] << ", ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    std::string line;
    std::string base;
    std::vector<std::string> dependencies;
};
```

While parsing every equation, we need to understand its dependencies.
Hence we need a tokenizer that will break the line into small tokens.
`a=b+c` is broken down into `[a, b, c]`, based on `=`, `+`, and `*`.

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const char* str)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    char plus = '+', star = '*', equals = '=';
    do {
        const char* begin = str;
        while( *str != equals
            && *str != plus
            && *str != star
            && *str          ) str++;
        result.push_back(std::string(begin, str));
    } while (0 != *str++);
    return result;
}
```

Now we need to create a `read` function.
The purpose of this function is a to read the input file and create a vector of equations out of it.
We also store a set of all `base` found in the `std::set<std::string> all_bases`. This would be used in comparison later.

```
std::vector<equation> read(std::set<std::string> & all_bases)
{
    std::ifstream file("in.txt");  // read input file
    // throw error if file could not be opened
    if(! file) throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");

    std::string line;
    std::vector<equation> equations;
    while(getline(file, line))
    {
        //de-structure the line
        std::vector<std::string> tokens = tokenize(line.c_str());

        // since '=' would be the first sperator, we find base at [0]
        std::string base = tokens[0];
        all_bases.insert(base);

        // now remove the first element, all that is left is dependencies
        tokens.erase(tokens.begin());

        equations.push_back(equation(line, base, tokens));
    }
    return equations;
}
```

Now time to create a function that will evaluate dependent or independent based on the criteria.
**Criteria** : *If any dependency is found to be a base, the equation is dependent.*

```
bool is_dependent(equation              const & equation,
                  std::set<std::string> const & all_bases)
{
    std::vector<std::string> deps = equation.dependencies;
    for(int j = 0; j < deps.size(); ++j)
    {
        std::string item = deps[j];
        if (all_bases.find(item) != all_bases.end())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you have logically broken your code into semantic values, it is easy to compose it into final program.
Here is the complete code, for reference -

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

struct equation
{
    equation(std::string              const & line,
             std::string              const & base,
             std::vector<std::string> const & dependencies)
        : line(line), base(base), dependencies(dependencies) {}

    void print() const {
        std::cout << "Equation => [" << line 
                  << "]; Base => [" << base 
                  << "]; Deps => [";
        for(int i = 0; i < dependencies.size(); ++i)
            std::cout << dependencies[i] << ", ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    std::string line;
    std::string base;
    std::vector<std::string> dependencies;
};

std::vector<std::string> tokenize(const char* str)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    char plus = '+', star = '*', equals = '=';
    do {
        const char* begin = str;
        while( *str != equals
            && *str != plus
            && *str != star
            && *str          ) str++;
        result.push_back(std::string(begin, str));
    } while (0 != *str++);
    return result;
}

std::vector<equation> read(std::set<std::string> & all_bases)
{
    std::ifstream file("in.txt");  // read input file
    // throw error if file could not be opened
    if(! file) throw std::runtime_error("Could not open file");

    std::string line;
    std::vector<equation> equations;
    while(getline(file, line))
    {
        //de-structure the line
        std::vector<std::string> tokens = tokenize(line.c_str());

        // since '=' would be the first seperator, we find base at [0]
        std::string base = tokens[0];
        all_bases.insert(base);

        // now remove the first element, all that is left is dependencies
        tokens.erase(tokens.begin());

        equations.push_back(equation(line, base, tokens));
    }
    return equations;
}

bool is_dependent(equation              const & equation,
                  std::set<std::string> const & all_bases)
{
    std::vector<std::string> deps = equation.dependencies;
    for(int j = 0; j < deps.size(); ++j)
    {
        std::string item = deps[j];
        if (all_bases.find(item) != all_bases.end())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void segregate(std::vector<equation> const & equations,
               std::set<std::string> const & all_bases,
               std::vector<equation>       & dependent,
               std::vector<equation>       & independent)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < equations.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (is_dependent(equations[i], all_bases))
            dependent.push_back(equations[i]); // here you can push in your desired vector
        else
            independent.push_back(equations[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> all_bases;
    std::vector<equation> equations = read(all_bases);

    std::vector<equation> dependent;
    std::vector<equation> independent;

    segregate(equations, all_bases, dependent, independent);

    std::cout << "Dependent Equations :\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < dependent.size(); ++i) dependent[i].print();

    std::cout << "\n\nIndependent Equations :\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < independent.size(); ++i) independent[i].print();

    return 0;
}
```

Test :
Input File (*in.txt*)

```
a=b+c
f=d*t
w=a+r
t=e+v
test=equi+valent*t
```

Output:

```
Dependent Equations :
Equation => [f=d*t]; Base => [f]; Deps => [d, t, ]
Equation => [w=a+r]; Base => [w]; Deps => [a, r, ]
Equation => [test=equi+valent*t]; Base => [test]; Deps => [equi, valent, t, ]

Independent Equations :
Equation => [a=b+c]; Base => [a]; Deps => [b, c, ]
Equation => [t=e+v]; Base => [t]; Deps => [e, v, ]
```

Comment: if OP uses this in his assignment then we hope he gives due credit to @badola and SO in general